# Scala Either[type1, type2]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a working example for the usage of Either:

```
val a: Either[Int, String] = {
if (true) 
    Left(42) // return an Int
else
    Right("Hello, world") // return a String
}
```

But the below doesn't work:
The condition "text" is just to determine if the input file is text file or parquet file

```
val a: Either[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = {
if (text) 
    spark.sparkContext.textFile(input_path + "/lineitem.tbl") // read in text file as rdd
else
    sparkSession.read.parquet(input_path + "/lineitem").rdd  //read in parquet file as df, convert to rdd
}
```

It gives me type mismatch errors:

```
<console>:33: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: scala.util.Either[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]
           spark.sparkContext.textFile(input_path + "/lineitem.tbl") // read in text file as rdd
                                      ^
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: scala.util.Either[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]
           sparkSession.read.parquet(input_path + "/lineitem").rdd  //read in parquet file as df, convert to rdd
```

Comment: Just wrap those two Spark expressions into Right and Left,  just like in first example.

Answer (score 2):

Your working example tells you exactly, what to do. Just wrap those two expressions returned by Spark into `Left` and `Right`:

```
val a: Either[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = {
  if (text)
     Left(spark.sparkContext.textFile(input_path + "/lineitem.tbl")) // read in text file as rdd
  else
     Right(sparkSession.read.parquet(input_path + "/lineitem").rdd)  //read in parquet file as df, convert to rdd
}
```

`Left` and `Right` are two classes, both extend from `Either`. You can create instances by using `new Left(expression)` and `new Right(expression)`. Since both of them are case classes, than the `new` keyword can be omitted and you simply use `Left(expression)` and `Right(expression)`.

Comment: You can also use `Either.cond` here which might look a bit cleaner.

Comment: oh, right, thank you. I didn't know that Left and Right here are mandatory wrappers. I thought they were just functions that to be returned.

Comment: @ygor  Can you provide a practical example of this at RDD level? I don't really get it.